# How can I take the value of a variable from a class which is in different file?

Tags: php, class

I have a user.php(class) , login.php and index.php. When I submit the form in index.php, form action goes to login.php and this file use User Class to verify if there exist who try to login. If true, redirect again to index.file. But I want to write the users full_name to index.php when he/she login. But I can not take full_name from class.

**NOTE :In the require_once  parts  of codes includes necessary file such as database.php, session.php, functions.php etc. So, there is no false about them and also there is no error in my functions. What I want is how to write full_name to index.php when user login.**

Here is user.php:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/database.php';

class User{

protected static $table_name="users";
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'email', 'password', 'first_name',
'last_name');

public $id;
public $email;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;

public function full_name() {
if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name)) {
  return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
} else {
  return "";
 }
}

public static function verify($user, $email="", $password="") {
global $database;

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users ";
$sql .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
$sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
$sql .= "LIMIT 1";
$result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);

    if (!empty($result_array)) {
        $user->first_name =  $result_array['first_name'];
        $user->last_name =   $result_array['last_name'];
        return array_shift($result_array);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }  

$user = new User();
//User class continue but i inserted necessary parts. All functions in the class works.
```

Here is login.php :

```
<?php require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/initialize.php'; ?>
<?
if($session->is_logged_in()) {
redirect_to("index.php");

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);


$found_user = User::verify($user,$email, $password);

if ($found_user) {
$session->login($found_user);

    redirect_to("index.php");

} else {

$message = "There is error about username/password";
echo $message;
}

} else {
$email = "";
$password = "";
} 
?>
```

Here is index.php :

```
<?php require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/initialize.php'; ?>

<?php

if($session->is_logged_in()) {
echo $user->full_name();

} else {
echo "No name";
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the output from full_name to a session variable. This can then be called to reproduce the name.

For information on using sessions within PHP, use the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php